# Performance gain from upgrading higher class SD card

Tags: external-sd, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the class rating of my MicroSD card relevant?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9627/is-the-class-rating-of-my-microsd-card-relevant)

If you've upgraded the SD card on your phone to a higher class, have you measured or noticed any significant performance difference?  What kinds of apps seemed most affected?

Comment: I noticed an overall improvement in the performance "feel" on my HTC Hero.  Proably because I was using a number of apps that do store data to SD.

Comment: This is the earlier question, so why was it closed?   What prevails - the earlier question or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A higher class card is going to give you faster read and write speeds to your SD card. So any apps that use or write data to the memory card will get a boost (one example would be the camera and gallery apps). Another possible example would be apps saved to the memory card. You probably, however, won't be able to tell a huge difference, or at least it won't be as noticeable as it would on a DSLR camera where high speed cards make a world of difference when taking fast, continuous shots (sports).